# Why there is still a inline specifier when member fuctions define inside class?

Tags: c++11, inline

The C++ ISO standard says: A function defined within a class definition is an inline function.

But look at the code as follows: [leveldb-skiplist](https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/master/db/skiplist.h)

```cpp
class template <typename Key, class Comparator>
class SkipList{
 public:
  /*
   ...
  */
 private:
  inline int GetMaxHeight() const {
    return max_height_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
  }
};
```

there is still an explicit inline specifier when GetMaxHeight is defined inside class.

So, I want to know why we still need an explicit inline when a function defined within a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't **need** it. It's redundant. Just like repeating `virtual` in the declaration of an `override`.

The grammar allows it, because it's a function definition, and there's no additional wording that bans it.